# Jquery play video or image in div with interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery array. What I want to do is fetch an image or video and play it until the specified interval and then play next video or image:

Here is my code:

```
var side_block_src= [{media:'images/172422009.jpg',interval:10},
                     {media:'images/172422001.jpg',interval:50},
                     {media:'images/172422009.jpg',interval:4}
                    ];


var sec = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < side_block_src.length; i++) {
  console.log('start');
  sec = side_block_src[side_block_src].interval*1000;
  setTimeout(function(){ 
   $('#setdata>iframe').attr('src',side_block_src[side_block_src].media); 
  },sec);
}
```

Why is it not working?

**Update**
 I made it more simple here is the working code

```
var i = 0;
show_next(i);
function show_next(i){
   if(i <=  side_block_src.length - i ){
      $('#setdata>iframe').attr('src',side_block_src[i+1].media); 
      setTimeout(function(){
         show_next(i + 1)
      }, side_block_src[i+1].interval * 1000); 
   } else {
     i=0;
     show_next(i);    
   }
```

}

Comment: Can you post your HTML code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
var i = -1;

showNext(i);

function showNext(i) {
    if (side_block_src.length - i > 1) {
     $('#setdata>iframe').attr('src',side_block_src[i+1].media); 
     setTimeout(function() 
                {
                  showNext(i + 1)
                }, side_block_src[i + 1].interval * 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
[anything slider jquery plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/anythingslider/) for this as below i have used

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ad/jquery.anythingslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ad/jquery.anythingslider.fx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ad/jquery.easing.1.2.js"></script>

$('#slider').anythingSlider({

    autoPlay: true,
    animationTime: 600,
    //expand       : true,
    // Autoplay video in initial panel, if one exists
    onInitialized: function(e, slider) {
        playvid(slider);
    },
    // pause video when out of view
    onSlideInit: function(e, slider) {
        var vid = slider.$lastPage.find('video');
        if (vid.length && typeof(vid[0].pause) !== 'undefined') {
            vid[0].pause();
        }
    },
    // play video
    onSlideComplete: function(slider) {

        playvid(slider);
    },
    // pause slideshow if video is playing
    isVideoPlaying: function(slider) {
        var vid = slider.$currentPage.find('video');
        return (vid.length && typeof(vid[0].pause) !== 'undefined' && !vid[0].paused && !vid[0].ended);
    }

});
```

and here is html code for it

```
<ul id="slider">
      <li class="panel5">
       <video class="Cmsvideo" controls autoplay>
        <source src="PATH_OF_VIDEO" type="video/EXTENTION_OF_VIDEO" >
         Your browser does not support the video tag. But you could include an iframe/embeded video here. </video>
      </li>

      <li><img src="PATH_OF_IMAGE" alt="" /></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I want to display image and videos without using any kind of sliders